# VS 2012 Page Inspector console in MVC not working

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have tried page inspector in web forms development and it works fine,
But in MVC it opens and in the console area it say's 
"Javascript Must be enabled in internet explorer"
now i'v checked everything and javascript is enabled,
Rebooted, Reinstalled, Nothing helps this issue...

working with page inspector should be a refreshing thing since 
MVC doesnt have a Designer view,
Does anyone had this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same issue and folowing this steps resolved it:

1. Enabled JS Debugging in Explorer as the message said
   and followed by this link:
   http://support.microsoft.com/gp/howtoscript
2. added this setting to the web.config
   at the
       `<appSetting>` section

   ```
   <add key='PageInspector:ServerCodeMappingSupport' value='Enabled'/>
   ```

   picked it up from this link:
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj204395.aspx
3. closed the visual studio and the Developement server

Comment: Step 2: What setting did you add to the web.config?  At which section?  Something apparently didn't copy and paste cleanly.

Comment: you right, i've fixed it now. the STACK editor 'swallow' the code row
:)
thanks.